# Return a select statement result

Tags: vba, excel

I have a function that has a select statement. I want this function to return a value which will be assigned to a cell, but I keep getting errors. Here is my code that calls the select statement function:

```
Sub ChangeSizes()

    For i = 2 To 50
        Range("G" & i) = LookupSize(Range("G" & i).value)
    Next i

End Sub
```

And here is my function that I want to return a value that will be assigned to the range:

```
Public Function LookupSize(Size) As String

    Select Case Size
        Case Is = 1
            Return '5/8" or 1/4"'
        Case Is = 43
            Return '3/8"'
    End Select

End Function
```

However, as it stands, I get an error: `Return without Gosub`

How do a return the result of the case statement and assign it to a range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You assign the return value to the function itself. Single quotes create comments, double quotes are used for quoted strings.

```
Public Function LookupSize(Size) As String

    Select Case Size
        Case 1
            LookupSize = "5/8" or "1/4"
        Case 43
            LookupSize = "3/8"
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: Aha! New to VBA and it drove me nuts getting this to work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Functions in VBA do not work using `Return`, but using the Function name as a variable. If you want to end the function after assigning it a value, you must also use `Exit Function`. Your code would look like this:

```
Public Function LookupSize(Size) As String

Select Case Size
    Case 1
        LookupSize = '5/8" or 1/4"' or whatever you want
    Case 43
        LookupSize = '3/8"' or whatever you want
End Select

End Function
```

Comment: No real point in adding `Exit Function` for every case statement. VBA Select Case 'short circuits' on the first match; nothing else is processed.

Comment: Thanks for the help! It works, but I have to give the check to the first answer since they responded first, but I will upvote.

Comment: @Jeeped I was just stating how to imitate the common `Return` statement in VBA, since `Return` ends the function itself, but assigning a value to a function in VBA don't.